# Not packaging language properties within main jar in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a fairly vanilla java desktop project built with maven 2. My problem is it puts the language properties (which reside in src/main/resources) into the main jar. This works but I want them packaged outside the jar so that is is easy for users to open the files in a text editor and modify them, how should I go about this ?

Comment: There's an `excludes` config setting in `jar` plugin.

Comment: @Andrew Logvinov so that makes sense, exclude them when building jar, add them to a different location using a assembly plugin. My problem is there doesn't seem to be a resource dir defined (i,e like ${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}

Comment: Just place them on a non-standard Maven directory (src/main/i18n for instance). Then configure the assembly plugin to make a specific artifact out of this directory. You will then have 1 main jar without translations, and another (ZIP, JAR, whatever) with only these i18n files.

Comment: @Tome that is what Ive done (i just what have preferred to keep them in the default location).Now my problem is I autogenerate the classpath for the jar, but I need to add the folder that the preferences will now reside in, how do I add extra classpath entries to the manifest created ?

Comment: MANIFEST.MF is tipically handled by the Maven archiver (http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html), for all plugin needed to interact with it.

Comment: I am using that but its not clear to me whether there is a way to add a classpath, I know I can just provide my own manfest.mf file but Id rather not because then I have to remember to update it every time a dependency changes

Comment: @Tome thks, found solution was to add <manifestEntries>